# Pushing IP routes to various VPN clients

Tags: vpn, cisco, openvpn, ipsec, juniper

With OpenVPN there is a well-known option "push" which allows to push an IP static route from the server to a connected OpenVPN client.
I would like to know if there is an equivalent of this option on:

1. L2TP over IPsec VPN?
2. IPsec (cisco compat) VPN?
3. Juniper SA (aka Juneos Pulse, aka NC) SSL VPN?

Comment: I can tell you that the Cisco VPN client family lets you set which subnets get routed through the VPN ("split tunneling"), but it doesn't have the flexibility to do any more creative route injection.

Comment: but that is configured on the cisco vpn client, right? I am talking about pushing route table from VPN server to a freshly connected client (like OpenVPN).

Comment: No, the server decides which networks are tunneled or not in their split tunnel implementation.

Comment: Thank you Shane, do you know situation with L2TP and Junos Pulse?

Comment: Can't say that I do, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to answer my own question after some research:

1. L2TP over IPsec VPN -- cannot push routes to clients (L2TP/PPP protocol limitations)
2. Cisco IPsec -- can push routes (thanks Shane, upvoted your comments)
3. Junos Pulse -- can push routes (according to docs, still to be tested)