# Sonicwall L2TP Server is using a "phantom" internal DHCP server

Tags: sonicwall, l2tp, dhcp-option, dhcp

Following a few articles on [options 121](https://serverfault.com/questions/343045/pushing-ip-routes-to-various-vpn-clients) and [249](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw7028), I'd like to push out routes to the L2TP VPN clients using the internal DHCP server on the Sonicwall.

However, the Sonicwall seems to be using a phantom internal DHCP server that's handing out IPs within the range defined in the L2TP Server > Configure... menu.

No leases show up under Network > DHCP Server (and without a scope defined, I didn't expect it to), but also no leases are showing up under DHCP over VPN either.

Seems strange to say the least; I've tried to add a dynamic scope and enable the DHCP Server, but it appears to be ignored in favor of whatever the L2TP Server on the Sonicwall is using.

Note: I am seeing "PPP IP" under the "Active L2TP Sessions" which is within that range defined.

Also, "Use Internal DHCP Server" and "Global VPN Client" are checked off under DHCP over VPN > Configure... (even though I don't believe L2TP is considered a Global VPN client)

Any ideas?